# Blender cycles baking, all black!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

So I'm having a bit of trouble with multiple material baking with Blender Cycles in my "Sale of the Century" game show set. I have this one piece (see below) that is made of six different materials. I have created my own texture map and unwrapped as needed. Fine. However, on the final bake, all the unwrapped areas keep coming out black.

I have recalculated my the normals. My image to where everything is going to be baked is called "contwalluv" and in the node editor, it is selected and not hooked up, for every material.

I baked this last night perfectly, but I also did it in the wee hours and forgot what I did, but I am obviously missing something.

I've tried using the UV input to no avail.

Note: the only thing that is being baked for now, until I perfect this, is that set piece in edit mode.

[image]

Minus the podiums for now, this is how I want the texture to be baked for the final render:

[image]

[Here's a link to the blend file and material](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7b1yS5Q8U9YNmcwSUpjLWhlYkE), Go nuts :)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show baking options, in particular what pass type did you bake? And what resulting texture would you like to get, only diffuse color or something else?

Comment: I want to do a combined. Everything baked, lighting, gloss etc., where all the lighting, shadowing, appears on the texture. The pieces would never move in an animation, only the camera.

Comment: I added the render result to show how the baking needs to be done. But unfortunately, all I get is black.

Comment: As it's combined it will take light and shading into acocunt. Are the emitting materials / lamps still lighting it up?

Comment: Yes. I had it done last night, but, stupid me, didn't write down what I did. So I'm back to square one with this.

Comment: Generally if you get black bake it's either because it's shaded bad (lighting/normals which you told you checked) or no information to bake (like when connecting diffuse shader but baking Emit pass). Try checking if UV map correspond to one baking is done with as well.

Comment: I added a link to the file for what it's worth. Totally lost at this point.